# Using values in nested lists with NULL-values as an if-condition R

Tags: r, if-statement, null, nested-lists

I have a dataframe containing a text column, which has shortend urls in it. I need to filter out some of these shortend URLs. Which URLs to filter is signaled by their values in another column, that basically is a nested list, inside a dataframe-column which itself is nested inside a column. In the nested list are mostly NULL-values and three different types of dataframes, which do share some columns. I'll want to use the values of shared columns as a filter.

The `dput(head(data$entities, 10))` output looks as following:

```
structure(list(mentions = list(structure(list(start = 0L, end = 5L, 
    username = "BILD", id = "9204502"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(start = 0L, end = 5L, username = "BILD", id = "9204502"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(start = 0L, end = 5L, username = "BILD", id = "9204502"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(start = 0L, end = 5L, username = "BILD", id = "9204502"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(start = 0L, end = 5L, username = "BILD", id = "9204502"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(start = 0L, end = 5L, username = "BILD", id = "9204502"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(start = 0L, end = 5L, username = "BILD", id = "9204502"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
    structure(list(start = c(0L, 17L), end = c(16L, 22L), username = c("Sebasti52801956", 
    "BILD"), id = c("1506995029205729292", "9204502")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 
    structure(list(start = c(0L, 11L), end = c(10L, 16L), username = c("Nico_FHKo", 
    "BILD"), id = c("3166027097", "9204502")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 
    structure(list(start = 0L, end = 5L, username = "BILD", id = "9204502"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L)), 
    hashtags = list(NULL, NULL, structure(list(start = c(82L, 
    106L, 133L), end = c(89L, 116L, 145L), tag = c("grünen", 
    "Bundestag", "Solidarität")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    3L)), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), urls = list(
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, structure(list(start = 6L, 
            end = 29L, url = "t.co/OC9Vo93CAp", expanded_url = "https://twitter.com/ThomasB59914994/status/1510264984034492417/photo/1", 
            display_url = "pic.twitter.com/OC9Vo93CAp", media_key = "16_1510264976740691973"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        structure(list(start = 141L, end = 164L, url = "t.co/fSa4TZmzFt", 
            expanded_url = "https://www.stern.de/digital/technik/sicher--klein-und-billig---china-baut-den-ersten-thorium-reaktor--30632008.html", 
            display_url = "stern.de/digital/techni…", images = list(
                structure(list(url = c("https://pbs.twimg.com/news_img/1557443927816404992/VfYVrEGt?format=jpg&name=orig", 
                "https://pbs.twimg.com/news_img/1557443927816404992/VfYVrEGt?format=jpg&name=150x150"
                ), width = c(1440L, 150L), height = c(810L, 150L
                )), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2)), 
            status = 200L, title = "Sicher, klein und billig – China baut den ersten Thorium-Reaktor", 
            description = "Er ist nicht größer als ein Badezimmer. In China wird ein Thorium-Reaktor in Betrieb genommen. 2030 soll es zur Serienproduktion kommen – die Mini-Reaktoren versprechen CO2-freien Strom ohne die Gefahr eines Gaus.", 
            unwound_url = "https://www.stern.de/digital/technik/sicher--klein-und-billig---china-baut-den-ersten-thorium-reaktor--30632008.html"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1L), 
        NULL, NULL), annotations = list(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL), cashtags = list(
        NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
        NULL)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

What i want to do now is to filter out those URLS in the text column, which correspont to a value of the display_url column inside a entities.url list stating "pic.".

Yet i tried this:

```
if (data$entities$urls != NULL) {
  if (data$entities$urls$display_url == "pic.*\\s*"){ 
    data$text <- gsub("http.*\\s*", "", data$text)
  }
}
```

But I always receive the error

> Error in if (replys_bu$entities$urls != NULL) { :argument is of length zero

I would appreciate any help

Comment: Don't compare to `NULL`, use `!is.null(data$entities$urls)` instead.

Comment: @Rui Barradas thanks for the contribution. Unfortunately the error just changed to `Error: 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'`

Comment: If `data$entities$urls` is the data.frame in the question, you also need the column name, `is.null(data$entities$urls$entities.url)`

Comment: The `data$entities$urls` already defines the column. I guess the problem is that the `url` column is a list, to which the is.null() function can not be applyed

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(data$entities)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(data$entities, 10))`. Without a way to faithfully reproduce the data set it's difficult to say what's going on.

Comment: Alright did it. thanks for the advice!

Comment: I cannot run the output of dput you posted (thanks, BTW), there's something wrong with it. Can you check that you copied and pasted it correctly and if not, repost?

Comment: Will do. I shortened it a bit previously thats probably where the problem came from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a vectorized way of replacing the strings in `data$text` by new values, depending on the url's values being not `NULL`.

**Note that `entities$urls` must be changed to `data$entities$urls`**

```
i_not_null <- which(!sapply(entities$urls, is.null))
displ_url <- sapply(entities$urls[i_not_null], `[[`, 'display_url')
i_text <- i_not_null * grepl("^pic.*\\s*", displ_url)
i_text <- i_text[i_text != 0]

data$text[i_text] <- gsub("http.*\\s*", "", data$text[i_text])
```